# Preserving Cases while Column Matching from List in Pandas

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, case-sensitive

I have a dataframe with strings with varying cases for column names as well as a list of lowercase strings.

```
a = [5, 5, 4, 6]
b = [4, 4, 4, 4]
c = [6, 8, 2, 3]
d = [8, 6, 4, 3]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': a,
                   'B_B': b,
                   'CC_Cc': c,
                   'Dd_DdDd': d})

cols = ['b_b', 'cc_cc', 'dd_dddd']
```

I want to select the columns in df that match the strings in cols while preserving the cases of the columns in df. I've been able to match the column names by making them all lowercase, but I'm not sure how save the original cases of the dataframe columns.

In this case I would want to create a new dataframe with only the columns in df from keep cols, but with their original cases. How would I go about doing this?

Desired output:

```
   B_B  CC_Cc  Dd_DdDd  
0    4      6        8  
1    4      8        6  
2    4      2        4  
3    4      3        3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.lower()` to convert the column names to lower case, then construct a logical series with `isin` method to select the columns; the column names will not be altered in this way:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.str.lower().isin(cols)]
```

[image]

An alternative method would be to use `filter` function, in regex specify a modifier `(?i)` to ignore case:

```
df.filter(regex="(?i)" + "|".join(cols))
```

[image]

Notice this regex method also matches column names that contain the pattern in `cols` list, if you want a exact match ignoring cases, you can add word boundaries in:

```
df.filter(regex="(?i)\\b"+"\\b|\\b".join(cols)+"\\b")
```

Comment: Awesome! Both these methods work like a charm. How do the run times compare? I'll be using these functions on pretty large datasets (hundreds of columns with thousands of rows).

Comment: I would not worry about the efficiency as much. Hundreds/thousands of columns/rows aren't that much since you are checking the index only here, not the entire data frame. So I would suggest whichever you prefer.